# Change image size only if both width and height are changed

Tags: css, responsive-design, electron, responsive, responsive-images

I have `background-image` and I need to change `background-size` by autoscaling with both screen width and height.

If only the height of the div/window changes, the image remains the same.

If both the height and the width of the window change at the same time, the image will be enlarged/reduced.

**Example:**

[image]

What should I add to my css?

```
...
background-image: url('some-image.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom center;
background-size: ??;
...
```

First of all I figured to calculate it by `min()` property, but I didn't code it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the @media rule.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 256px) and (max-height: 256px){
...{
background-size: Your Size; 
}
}
```

This should change the img width and height to 256px when the browser window is 256px wide or less.

Comment: This method is not scalable, im working with relative screen size. I am looking for some autoscaling solution.